# R- split list deleting blank spaces

Tags: r, string, split

I'm trying to split elements from a list leaving no white spaces. If my string is:

```
formula_nn<-flag_compro ~ A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1 + A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2 + 
  A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3 + A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4 + A_CLI_promociones + 
  A_CLI_dias_cliente + A_CLI_sucursales + A_CLI_promos_enviadas + 
  A_CLI_promos_compras + A_CLI_produni + A_CLI_frecuencia_compra + 
  county + A_CLI_mid + A_M_0705_monto + A_GEOMKG_p_una_unidad + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_20_unidades + A_GEOMKG_p_casas_nuevas + A_GEOMKG_p_casas_viejas + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_3_autos + A_GEOMKG_p_auto + A_GEOMKG_p_camina + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_posgrado + A_GEOMKG_p_nativos + A_GEOMKG_p_extranjeros + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_ciudadanos + flag_incluido + monto_sucs + PComSPEnv + 
  PEnvSDCli + MSucSPrComp + suc1_bin + suc2_bin + suc4_bin
```

I tried:

```
strsplit(as.character(formula_nn), split="\\+")
```

But I still get the blanks.
I also tried:

```
a<-gsub("[ + ]",' ' ,as.character(formula_nn))
b<-strsplit(as.character(formula_nn), split=" ")
```

But if I do b[3] I get the almost full list and still with '+'.

Comment: Instead of `b<-strsplit(as.character(formula_nn), split=" ")` you should do `b<-strsplit(as.character(a), split=" ")`?? (put the just created `a` instead of `formula_nn`), also, why not just `strsplit(as.character(formula_nn), split="[ + ]")`?

Comment: Or you could do `scan(text=gsub('[^[:alnum:]_]+', ' ', formula_nn),what='', quiet=TRUE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about `terms` and `all.vars`?

```
formula_nn <- "flag_compro ~ A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1 + A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2 + 
  A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3 + A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4 + A_CLI_promociones + 
  A_CLI_dias_cliente + A_CLI_sucursales + A_CLI_promos_enviadas + 
  A_CLI_promos_compras + A_CLI_produni + A_CLI_frecuencia_compra + 
  county + A_CLI_mid + A_M_0705_monto + A_GEOMKG_p_una_unidad + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_20_unidades + A_GEOMKG_p_casas_nuevas + A_GEOMKG_p_casas_viejas + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_3_autos + A_GEOMKG_p_auto + A_GEOMKG_p_camina + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_posgrado + A_GEOMKG_p_nativos + A_GEOMKG_p_extranjeros + 
  A_GEOMKG_p_ciudadanos + flag_incluido + monto_sucs + PComSPEnv + 
  PEnvSDCli + MSucSPrComp + suc1_bin + suc2_bin + suc4_bin"

str(formula_nn <- as.formula(formula_nn))
# Class 'formula' length 3 flag_compro ~ A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1 + A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2 + A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3 +      A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4 + A_CLI_promociones + A_CLI_dias_cliente + A_CLI_sucursales +  ...
# ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 


terms(formula_nn)
all.vars(formula_nn)

# [1] "flag_compro"             "A_CLI_monto_sucursal_1"  "A_CLI_monto_sucursal_2" 
# [4] "A_CLI_monto_sucursal_3"  "A_CLI_monto_sucursal_4"  "A_CLI_promociones"      
# [7] "A_CLI_dias_cliente"      "A_CLI_sucursales"        "A_CLI_promos_enviadas"  
# [10] "A_CLI_promos_compras"    "A_CLI_produni"           "A_CLI_frecuencia_compra"
# [13] "county"                  "A_CLI_mid"               "A_M_0705_monto"         
# [16] "A_GEOMKG_p_una_unidad"   "A_GEOMKG_p_20_unidades"  "A_GEOMKG_p_casas_nuevas"
# [19] "A_GEOMKG_p_casas_viejas" "A_GEOMKG_p_3_autos"      "A_GEOMKG_p_auto"        
# [22] "A_GEOMKG_p_camina"       "A_GEOMKG_p_posgrado"     "A_GEOMKG_p_nativos"     
# [25] "A_GEOMKG_p_extranjeros"  "A_GEOMKG_p_ciudadanos"   "flag_incluido"          
# [28] "monto_sucs"              "PComSPEnv"               "PEnvSDCli"              
# [31] "MSucSPrComp"             "suc1_bin"                "suc2_bin"               
# [34] "suc4_bin"
```