# How to find out class of terms in formula

Tags: r

Given a `formula` object, I can find out the `class` of the terms by

```
> lapply(model.frame(~Type*Plant+uptake,data=CO2),class)
$Type
[1] "factor"

$Plant
[1] "ordered" "factor" 

$uptake
[1] "numeric"
```

But this requires a call to `model.frame` and I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Seems like some type of a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651618/r-split-list-deleting-blank-spaces/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `all.vars` function to extract the variable names from a formula object.

```
form <- ~Type*Plant+uptake
all.vars(form)
# [1] "Type"   "Plant"  "uptake"
```

Find the class of variables:

```
lapply(CO2[all.vars(form)], class)
# $Type
# [1] "factor"
# 
# $Plant
# [1] "ordered" "factor" 
# 
# $uptake
# [1] "numeric"
```